# gcloud functions deploy fails with .cloudignore file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcloudignore

When deploying a simple hello_world app to Google Cloud Functions using gcloud, I get the following error message:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: Build error details not available

It took me quite a while to figure out that this is due to my .cloudignore file:

.cloudignore

```
# Ignore everything
*

# Except these files:
!main.py
!requirements.txt
```

What seems to be the problem with this file? And what is a better way achieve what I want, i.e. ignore all files except main.py and requirements.txt?

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: could this be a simple typo-problem? To my knowledge, the file is called .gcloudignore
(with a 'g')

Answer (score 0):

The `.gcloudignore` file follows the same pattern as the `.gitignore`. Considering that, using only the `*`, could ended up being a recursively method that would ended up messing the other files that would be excepted.

Considering that, I would recommend you to give a try using the below configuration for your `.gcloudignore` file - this way, the slash should eliminate this undesired behavior:

```
# Ignore everything
/*

# Except these files:
!main.py
!requirements.txt
```

A reminder is that the file needs to be in the same directory that the `main.py` and `requirements.txt` file are, so the path works correctly. Otherwise, you will need to set the whole path in the `.gcloudignore`.

In these below posts from the Community - on specific regarding GCP and other on `.gitignore` - that might help you, since the syntax for both of them are the same and there are some other options and ideas on how to achieve it.

- [How to ignore files when running `gcloud app deploy`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434270/how-to-ignore-files-when-running-gcloud-app-deploy)
- [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but unfortunately that's not working, it produces the same unspecific error as above.

Comment: Hi @Sebastian thanks for confirming. Have you checked the above articles that I provided and tried other options? In case none of them solve your case and everything is well configured - files on the same directories, etc. - I would recommend you to reach out directly the [Google's Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) so they can help you investigate what might be affecting your file. Since the `.gcloudignore` file is well configured, it should be working as expected.

Comment: Yeah it seems like what's working for .gitignore is not necessarily working for .cloudignore. As I'm not on a premium support plan reaching out to Google's support unfortunately won't work...

Comment: Similar issues here, `gcloud meta list-files-for-upload` correctly handles the `!` rules,  but the actual `gcloud functions deploy` mishandles them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's a bug with `gcloud functions` handling of `.gitignore`; `gcloud app` and `gcloud meta list-files-for-upload` don't suffer from the same problem, handling the `!` rules correctly.

A workaround proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54959530/217588) to a similar question works for me, explicitly include the `.` directory e.g. add a rule like this.

```
!.
```